# Do the other infinity stones 'melt people' like the Power stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

In *Guardians of the Galaxy* we see that the power stone has the tendency to fry people when they hold it too long, unless it's attached to something.

In most of the interactions of the other stones, we see that they're contained in something, so they don't really do anything (I can't say anything about the Aether, since I haven't seen *Thor:the Dark World*) with the exception of the Tesseract "vaporizing" Red Skull at the end of *Captain America: The First Avenger*

> which of course, we realize it was a teleport

Is this a quirk exclusive to the power stone, or do the others have this issue as well?

Comment: The Aether does do a bit of a mischief to Jane Foster in *The Dark World*, but not in quite the same way as the Power Stone.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that the stones on their own may not interact with the world the same way they do when inside certain containment units (e.g. the Tesseract).

Comment: @V2Blast I guess you've got a point. We've never really seen anyone hold a bare infinity stone outside of the power stone.

Comment: @Paul My dirty mind interpreted that differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the entity (or entities as we see in The Guardians Of The Galaxy the whole team gets together and wields the power stone) wielding the infinity stone (depending on the stone) is powerful enough or worthy enough to wield it's power, then there wont be a problem.

In Captain America: The First Avenger the Red Skull touches the Tessaract with his bare hands and he gets teleported to another location by the Space Stone which is within the Tessaract, even though the Space stone wasn't directly held the stones are sentient and because the Red Skull tried to use it's power he was beamed away by the stone. 
So not all stones will "fry people" but **they do have their own safety mechanisms.**

Also, in Doctor Strange we can see the time stone being wielded without any issues.

In Avegers: Age Of Ultron we see Vision having the Mind Gem on his head and even wielding it without any issues.

> In avengers infinity war we see thanos holding many of the stones bare handed, as he is powerful enough he’s not affected by them.Also Doctor Strange in a way held the time stone just before he gives it to Thanos and we don’t see anything happen to Doctor Strange at that moment.

---

***Additionally***,

In the comics there were instance the stone might end up being shattered,
this happened when Captain America held the time stone in the comics,
[image: Captain America holds the Time Stone]

Comment: Hi, while an interesting answer, the scope of this question is set to the MCU, not the comics. As the canons are different, it is preferred one use information from the MCU films to answer the question, if comics are needed they should be added as additional details.

Comment: The Time Stone is not held bare-handed when in Doctor Strange the way the Power Stone is in GotG when it "melts people". It's encased in the Eye of Agomotto which is opened in order to use its power, but it is never directly touched by Strange. Thus we do not know if humans are capable of holding it bare-handed.The Mind Stone is attached to a synthetic being made of techno-organic Vibranium, so, again, we do not know if holding the Mind Stone bare-handed is possible for a human.

Comment: @vynsane Yes we can’t tell for sure because there’s not much evidence in the MCU of humans holding the stones bare handed, that is why I have mentioned wielding the stones.